# Load db.sql file into db using PDO

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, mariadb, file-get-contents

i use `file_get_contents` to get the queries from the file but now how can i load all of them into a mariadb database by using PDO?
With mysqli i know there is a function called `mysqli_multi_query` is there another function that does the same but with PDO?

Comment: `pdo->exec` will probably not complain when executing multiple queries

Answer (score 0):

Do not use multi-query.

Is this a CSV file?  If so, you should not need `file_get_contents`; instead use `LOAD DATA INFILE ...`